# We do not have our password, cannot access our account!

Tags: login

the folks who installed Magento on our website are long gone. The assistant who had the login info is now gone and did not leave the login info. I am new here, need to make some changes to our website and need to access our Magento/admin area but have no password and seemingly no way to have it emailed to myself as my email is not associated with the account. We already have an account and use Magento daily for sales of our company. Can anyone help with this? I can't even get in to our account, to be able to change the password! 
Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to the server (db)? See http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/recover/resetting-admin-password

Answer (score 3):

There are several options in how to do this, i'm going to share two of the easiest methods.

1- If you have MySQL access, go to the database. Select the 'admin_user' table and change one of your admin users email.

[image: Admin User]

Once that is complete, go to your backend and click on the "Forget Password" link and have it e-mailed to you.

Or

2- Go to the website root, add a file called "admin.php" and enter the following information into that file:

```
<?php
require_once('./app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();

try {
$user = Mage::getModel('admin/user')
->setData(array(
'username'  => 'youradminname',
'firstname' => 'Admin',
'lastname'    => 'Admin',
'email'     => 'youremail@email.com',
'password'  =>'password123',
'is_active' => 1
))->save();

} catch (Exception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
exit;
}

//Assign Role Id
try {
$user->setRoleIds(array(1))
->setRoleUserId($user->getUserId())
->saveRelations();

} catch (Exception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
exit;
}

echo "User created successfully";

?>
```

I didn't create the code above, I believe it was Inchoo. I just have held onto the script for some time.

Make sure to delete the file after use.

Answer (score 0):

1. See [Resetting Admin Password](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/recover/resetting-admin-password) (assuming you have access to the db)

   UPDATE admin_user SET password=CONCAT(MD5('qXpassword'), ':qX') WHERE username='admin';

‘qX’ would be changed to whatever you want it to be and same goes for ‘password’

2. Assuming that the user was using a corporate email, ask a admin to reset there password or delete that email account and retrieve it from the catch all